# Pyspark Fault of textFile: py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o12.textFile

Tags: pyspark

I'm a freshman of pyspark.

My computer installs: spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7, Java 19.0.1, scala 2.13.10, Hadoop 3.0.0.

There is an error as following when I want to read a local file:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf=SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName('WordCount')
    sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
    rdd_init=sc.textFile("file:///D:/PythonCode/pythonProject/letters.txt")
```

No matter change it to anyone of the following:

rdd_init=sc.textFile("file:///D:/PythonCode/pythonProject/letters.txt")

rdd_init=sc.textFile("file://D:/PythonCode/pythonProject/letters.txt")

rdd_init=sc.textFile("file:///letters.txt")
rdd_init=sc.textFile("letters.txt")

rdd_init=sc.textFile("file://./letters.txt")

rdd_init=sc.textFile("file:///D:/PythonCode/pythonProject/letters.csv")

The error is always:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o12.textFile

Detail is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PythonCode/pythonProject/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    rdd_init=sc.textFile("file:///D:/PythonCode/pythonProject/letters.txt")
  File "D:\PythonCode\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 599, in textFile
    return RDD(self._jsc.textFile(name, minPartitions), self,
  File "D:\ProgramFiles\Spark\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "D:\ProgramFiles\Spark\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o12.textFile.
: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field transient java.lang.Object[] java.util.ArrayList.elementData accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @776a6d9b
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:387)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:363)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:311)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$$anonfun$getClassInfo$3.apply(SizeEstimator.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$$anonfun$getClassInfo$3.apply(SizeEstimator.scala:330)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.getClassInfo(SizeEstimator.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.visitSingleObject(SizeEstimator.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.org$apache$spark$util$SizeEstimator$$estimate(SizeEstimator.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.estimate(SizeEstimator.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.SizeTracker$class.takeSample(SizeTracker.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.SizeTracker$class.afterUpdate(SizeTracker.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.SizeTrackingVector.$plus$eq(SizeTrackingVector.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.DeserializedValuesHolder.storeValue(MemoryStore.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1165)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putIterator(BlockManager.scala:914)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putSingle(BlockManager.scala:1481)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1489)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:1035)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:1027)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:699)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.hadoopFile(SparkContext.scala:1027)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$textFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$textFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:828)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:699)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:828)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.textFile(JavaSparkContext.scala:179)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

I want to test pyspark on my computer as local mode.